# $A$, $B$ and $C$ can do a ...

Tags: arithmetic

$A$, $B$ and $C$ can do a piece of work in $30$, $40$ and $50$ days respectively. If $A$ and $B$ work in alternate days started by $A$ and they get the assistance of $C$ all the days, find in how many days the whole work will be finished?

My Attempt:

In $30$ days, $A$ does $1$ work.
In $1$ day, $A$ does $\frac {1}{30}$ work.

In $40$ days, $B$ does $1$ work.
In $1$ day, $B$ does $\frac {1}{40}$ work.

In $50$ days, $C$ does $1$ work.
In $1$ day, $C$ does $\frac {1}{50}$ work.

In $1$ day, $(A+C)$ do $\frac {4}{75}$ work.

In $1$ day, $(B+C)$ do $\frac {9}{200}$ work.

I could not solve from here. Please help.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose there are $\;x\;$ days $\;A+C\;$ work together, and $\;y\;$ days $\;B+C\;$ work together, then

$$\frac{4x}{75}+\frac{9y}{200}=1\stackrel{\cdot600}\implies 32x+27y=600$$

There are, of course, infinite solutions, but we'd like $\;x,y\;$ to be *positive integers*, and this restricts seriously the possibilities: $\;x=12\;,\;\;y=8\;$ fulfill the conditions.

Further explanation: since $\;32x\;$ is *always* even, observe that $\;y\;$ must be even too.

I'm now paying attention to the data that the working days are *alternating*, and thus Pieter21's solution is the way to go, though there is no "exact* number of full work days.

Comment: Could you please explain.how did you get the values of $x$ and $y$?

Comment: @user354073 In this particular case, by try and error...and some estimation. As we need that $\;32x=600-27y\;$, check the very first **even** values of $\;y\;$ .... Observe that you won't have to go very high as the values wanted are *positive* , and $\;27\cdot22\;$ is close already to $\;600\;$ , so at most you'll need to check $\;\frac{22}2=11\;$ multiples of $\;27\;$ .

Answer (score 2):

Divide the work in $600$ pieces (the least common multiple of the dividers).

- $A$ does $\frac{600}{30} = 20$ pieces a day every other day.
- $B$ does $\frac{600}{40} = 15$ pieces a day every other day.
- $C$ does $\frac{600}{50} = 12$ pieces each day.

So alternating, $32 = 20+12 = A + C$, and $27 = 15+12 = B + C$ pieces of work get done each day.

We need to get $600$ pieces of work done, and because of the alternation, we get $59 = 32+27$ pieces done in two days.

After $\lfloor{\frac{600}{59}}\rfloor = 10$ alternations ($20$ days), $10$ pieces are left ($600 - 59 \times 10$).

The final $10$ pieces get done in $1$ day, as it is less than $32$.

So in total: $21$ days.

Comment: I did not understand? Could you please clarify a bit more?

Comment: I edited the answer. If still not clear, please try to explain which part is not clear.

Comment: How did you get: Adoes 20 a day every other day,B
does 15 a day every other day, and C
does 12 each day.?

Comment: @Pieter21 You've been a member for over two years and have posted some 139 answers. I think it is about time to learn how to type with MathJax, lest your answers will go unappreciated because it is hard to read them.

Answer (score 0):

A takes-> 30 days, B takes-> 40 days, C takes-> 50 days
Total unit of work they have to finish is(LCM of 30,40,50) i.e 600 units
It means 
A does -> 20 unit of work in 1 day, B does -> 15 unit in 1 day and C does 12 units in 1 day.

On 1st day A+C does 32 units out of 600, On 2nd day B+C does next 27 units of remaining work.

It means they do 59 unit of work in 2 days. In 20 days 590 units will be done by them. Remaining 10 units are done by A+C in \frac{10}{32}$$ days.

Total days they took to finish the work 600/59 =10 \frac{5}{16}$$ = 20 \frac{5}{16}$$ days.